# Find depth of each category in table

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data

I have a table called Categories with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `Categories` (
    `CatID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `UserID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `CatName` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    `Parent` int(200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`CatID`)
)
```

I'm looking to create an SQL statement to find the depth of each category and I can't figure this one out.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The answer to this question can be very database (SQL, Oracle, MySQL, etc..) and version dependent (SQL Server 2000, 2005, or 2008?).    What DB and what version?

Comment: @EBarr: AUTO_INCREMENT is MySQL, but you are right to ask

Comment: MySQL doesn't have hierarchical functionality - see: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html

Comment: @OMG: The article is not available at this location anymore. New address: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of your issue is that your database structure isn't meant to solve this problem.
If i was in your place , i would restructure that table in two separate tables ( solution known as Closure Tables ).

Lets assume that you use MySQL , `<rant>` like with linux , people who never specify the distro are unaware that ubuntu is not the only distributions `</rant>`.

```
CREATE TABLE Categories (
   node_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
   label VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Closure (
   ancestor INT NOT NULL,
   descendant INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (ancestor, descendant),
   FOREIGN KEY (ancestor) REFERENCES Nodes(node),
   FOREIGN KEY (descendant) REFERENCES Nodes(node)
);

SELECT count( Categories.node_id ) AS depth
FROM Closure AS Des
     JOIN Closure AS Anc ON (Anc.descendant = Des.descendant)
     JOIN Categories ON ( Categories.node = Anc.ancestor)
WHERE Des.ancestor = 1 AND Des.descendant != Des.ancestor
GROUP BY Des.descendant;
```

This would calculate the depth for each node. And i in this setup you actually can have each Subcategory be a descendant of multiple Categories.

You can find more information about Closure table [in this blog post](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2010/03/rendering-trees-with-closure-tables.html) , or treat yourself to a book called ["SQL Antipatterns"](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/bksqla/sql-antipatterns).

Comment: I remember when gentoo was teh Linux...  Do the hardcores still use Slack?

Comment: @OMG-Ponies yeah , slackware is still for enthusiasts. And on the BSD-like ( ones with streamlined system for building stuff from source ) side of linux distros there is not only Gentoo, but a new disto : Arch

Comment: <rant>Using a self referencing hierarchical table is not really an anti-pattern. When using a DBMS that supports hierarchical queries (like nearly every major DBMS except MySQL) retrieving the data is a piece of cake and very efficient.</rant> But I like the idea with the closure table.